# Issue while working with JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

While working with json,I got the string

```
var result=  "[\"Emp1\", \"46\", \"46\", \"46\"], [\"Emp2\", \"113\", \"117\", \"117\"]"
```

I need to convert the above json as

```
var jsonRes=[["Emp1", "46", "46", "46"], ["Emp2", "113", "117", "117"]]
```

how to do this conversion

Comment: the result is two arrays so you need to wrap it to have one array with two sub arrays: `JSON.parse("[" + result + "]");`

Comment: This is invalid Json, Please validate here http://pro.jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```js
var result = "[\"Emp1\"46\",\"46\",\"46\"],[\"Emp2\",\"113\",\"117\",\"117\"]";

console.log(
  result.slice(1, -1).split('],[').map(function(v) {
    return v.match(/[^",]+/g);
  })
)
```

**UPDATE :** In case if you are added `\",` in `\"Emp1\"46\"` then you can use `JSON.parse` by making the string valid JSON.

```js
var result = "[\"Emp1\",\"46\",\"46\",\"46\"],[\"Emp2\",\"113\",\"117\",\"117\"]";

console.log(
  JSON.parse('['+result+']')
)
```

Comment: Did you even try your own snippet...?

Answer (score 2):

The result is not valid JSON and double quotes were not properly escaped. You may use JSON.parse if you have properly escaped the result.

```js
var result= '[\"Emp1\",\"46\",\"46\"],[\"Emp2\",\"113\",\"117\",\"117\"]'

 result = "["+result+"]"

console.log(JSON.parse(result)[0]);
```